# Temperature decay model

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, thermal-radiation, thermal-conductivity, models

I am looking for a temperature decay model/formula that will help me understand at what rate does a hot object lose it's influence per distance.

`Hot object` = an object with a temperature higher than the average room temperature

`Influence/distance` = if we put a thermometer and measure the temperature at `n` distance from the object, what will be the difference between the room average and the temperature at that point?

Now obviously I would like a continuous function, not a discrete one. So how can I model the temperature `n` distance away from the hot object?

Obviously the object will heat the room, so it is a transient problem, but for sake of simplicity I am only curious what happens at `T0` or `T1`. But if you can help me with the transient model, then all the better.

Comment: I would say there is no such function as you are looking for. It really depends on many factor.  For example, when the temperature of hot object is high, radiation heat transfer can not be ignored. Or object shape will affect the heat transfer as well.

Comment: @user115350 But I really need a general formula. What if we just assume that it's a point. So if we would calculate the heat transfer and temperature change betwen 2 points, A and B. Would such model exist?